# How to implement Packery library with Tumblr

Tags: javascript, css, tumblr, grid-layout, packery

I followed the 'Getting started' tutorials on the Packery website, but I still can't get my tumblr photo posts to work at all with the library. I'm not sure what I need to change or add since the Packery tutorials are pretty vague.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <script src="http://packery.metafizzy.co/packery.pkgd.min.js"></script>

 <script>


   var postsContainer = document.querySelector('#posts');
   var pckry = new Packery( postsContainer, {
   //options

   itemSelector: '.container',
   gutter:5
    });

   pckry.bindResize(postsContainer);

   </script>

 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monofett|Varela|Londrina+Shadow'   rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

 <!--  fonts

 font-family: 'Monofett', cursive;
 font-family: 'Varela', sans-serif;
 font-family: 'Londrina Shadow', cursive;
 -->

 <title>{Title}</title>
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}">


   <!-- DEFAULT COLORS -->
    <meta name="color:Background" content="#eee"/>
    <meta name="color:Content Background" content="#fff"/>
    <meta name="color:Text" content="#000"/>

  <style type="text/css">

  *{margin:0px;
    padding:0px;}

  html{height:100%;}   

  body{
     background-color:{color:Background};
     margin:0px;
     height:100%;
   }



    #sideBar{
     background-color:{color:Content Background};
     width:150px;
     height:100%;  ;
     margin:auto 0;
     margin-right:20px;
     padding-left:10px;
     float:left;
    }

   h1{font-family: 'Monofett', cursive;;
   font-size:43px;
   margin-bottom:25px;
   color:black;}

   h2{ font-family: 'Varela', sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    margin-bottom:10px;}

   p{margin-bottom:10px;}  

   a:link, a:visited{font-family: 'Varela', sans-serif;
    font-size:.95em;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
    -webkit-transition:margin-left 1s, margin-right 1s, color .5s;
    -webkit-timing-function:ease;}

   #arrow{color:black;
      font-family: 'Varela', sans-serif;
      fonr-size:.95em;
      -webkit-transition:color.5s;
      -wekit-timing-function:ease;}




    a:hover{color:white;
        margin-left:10px;
        margin-right:40px;} 




    nav{margin-left:0px}  





   #posts{

   float:left;
   list-style:none;

   }

    .postPhoto{

    float:left;

    margin:5px;

    }  

    #wrapper{
      height:100%;

      width:700px;
    }    

   .pagination{display:none;}

   </style>
   </head>

   <body>

   <div id="wrapper">

   <div id="sideBar">
   <h1>{Title}</h1>
   <nav>    
   <p> <a href ="">Music </a>  <span id="arrow"> >> </span>  </p>
   <p> <a href="">Code </a> <span id="arrow"> >> </span>  </p>
   <p> <a href="">Shop </a> <span id="arrow"> >> </span>  </p>
   <p> <a href="">About </a> <span id="arrow"> >> </span>  </p>
   </nav>       
   </div>


   <div id="posts"> <!--content -->
       {block:Posts}

        <div class="container">    
            {block:Photo}
                <div class="postPhoto">
            <img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" width="200px"/>

                    {block:Caption}
                        <div class="caption">{Caption}</div>
                    {/block:Caption}
                </div>
            {/block:Photo}

                {block:Video}
                <li class="post video">
                    {Video-250}

                    {block:Caption}
                        <div class="caption">{Caption}</div>
                    {/block:Caption}
                </li>
            {/block:Video}

        </div><!--end container -->

        {/block:Posts}        
     </div>
    </div>         
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the site? Are you getting any console errors? Perhaps hosting your JS on dropbox isn't the best idea? You can use Tumblr's own file uploader to host theme files.

Comment: Well, Packery is throwing an error: http://cl.ly/image/2g3f1j0R3v18

Comment: I changed the link for packery to : `http://packery.metafizzy.co/packery.pkgd.min.js`. Still gives a null but somewhere else. Could the Packery link to the script be the problem? It's straight from the source. http://tinyurl.com/kguq9x3

Comment: I think I overlooked something. On the Packery website, it says to install 'bower'. I'm guessing that since I didn't install Bower that's why it's not working. I was thinking that it would just work with the Packery link to the library itself. If so, how would I install Bower if I'm using tumblr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things.

1) Your `#posts` container is floated and therefore is only as wide as the content within it. Even if Packery *was* working it would just line them all up in a single column. You'll need to apply it a width. If you're not concerned with IE8, you can do something like this:

```
#posts {
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 180px);
    width:    -moz-calc(100% - 180px);
    width:         calc(100% - 180px);
}
```

2) The Packery error is odd, I'm not entirely sure what's causing it. But by butting this simple bit of JS through the Console, I was able to get it running:

```
var container = document.querySelector('#posts');
var pckry = new Packery( container, {
  // options
  itemSelector: '.container',
  gutter: 10
});
```

Make sure this code comes at the end of your document, right before the closing `</body>`.

3) Since your posts are images, you'll need to make sure you're providing them a width and height so that Packery knows how big each post is. Unfortunately, since you're not using a standard Tumblr width, you'll need to include the imagesLoaded plugin and place your code inside its callback.

Easy way using jQuery:

```
var container = document.querySelector('#posts');
container.imagesLoaded( function() {

    var pckry = new Packery( container, {
      // options
      itemSelector: '.container',
      gutter: 10
    });

});
```

If you were using a standard Tumblr size (like 250px) you'd be able to simply add a width and height attribute to each image and not need to worry about using imagesLoaded, like this:

```
<img alt="" src="{PhotoURL-250)" height="{PhotoHeight-250}" width="{PhotoWidth-250}" />
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's actually working. The changes I made to the `#posts` container make images layout correctly but when resizing the window or reloading the page there are no fluid animations of the images being organized by the packery library. Also taking out the packery script still gives the same results.

Comment: Add the Packery JS back into the theme and I can have a look. You'll want to use this to watch browser resizing: http://packery.metafizzy.co/methods.html#bindresize

Comment: Ok I added the JS back and added the bindResize, some new errors though: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerWidth' of undefined ` Probably due to my incorrect usage of `pckry.bindResize(postsContainer);`

Comment: Ah, make sure Packery is coming at the end of your page, right before the closing `</body>`. Updated answer with another note.